# Consume WooCommerce REST API with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, rest, woocommerce, fetch

With Wordpress REST API i can simply fetch posts or anything available with JavaScript Fetch API (like the example code) or something similar.

Since WooCommerce REST API have auth keys the only way to fetch something is having the keys as query parameters, but i can't expose the keys in JavaScript. So how can i do it safely?

```
fetch('https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(posts => {
    posts.forEach(post => {
      console.log(post.title.rendered);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Are the auth keys specific to the individual user and would be generated specifically for them in the code? In which case it's not so much of a risk if the user could potentially discover their own access key? That's the impression I get from briefly reading https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/

Answer (score 0):

you cannot. all js source is visible by the client.
you can have backend middleware, which will not require the key, but which will load, using the key from the real source and proxy the data.

Comment: But in doing such a thing you effectively negate the security protection intended by the auth keys, because anyone can then make a request to the middleware and get a response without having to be identified.